# How does "Your comment is awaiting moderation" work?

Tags: plugin-development, comments

The question here is if someone could help me to make the comment "Your comment is awaiting moderation" work correctly for custom page. It works ok for standard Wordpress page but not for my own page.

I use native wp function `get_comments()` and `wp_list_comments()` to get and display comments. If I submit new comment that awaits moderation the comment and the message `Your comment is awaiting moderation` is accessible to anyone.

I always thought that the awaiting comments is visible only to the user that submitted the comment. If it's not the case what is purpose of the message if anyone is able to see the comment? The one purpose I can think of is that it is a kind of notice that this comment will be moderated in the future and could be deleted.

If really everyone can see the comment that it would make sense if the message reads `This comment is awaiting moderation`. Is there any way how to change the text of the message from a plugin?

## UPDATE

ok, so it is my code. If I display the page using standard wp way it works ok. If I use my code it doesn't work (meaning everyone can see the comment with awaiting message. Would someone know what I need to add to my code to make it work? I use just two above functions. The code is something like that

```
$comments =     get_comments(array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'status' => 'approve' 
));
    wp_list_comments(array(
//              'page' => 1,
        'per_page' => 10,
        'avatar_size'   => 16,
    ), $comments);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember awaiting moderation message *should* be only visible to author of the comment. If it is displaying otherwise it might be faulty caching implementation or other code interfering.

The customization of it depends on where it is coming from - it can be WP core, core theme or third party theme using same string.

Comment: ok, so it is my code. If I display the page using standard wp way it works ok. If I use my code it doesn't work (meaning everyone can see the comment with awaiting message. Would you know what I need to add to my code to make it work? I use just two above functions.

Comment: My question is how make it so the text "Your comment is awaiting moderation" with my php code. It is obvious that I am missing something. but what?